# Using ui-router in the ionic framework in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app that uses the ionic framework. This in-turn uses the ui-router. Currently, I have a pretty basic two-page app. However, it will expand to be much larger. At this time, I get an error when I transition from my first view to my second view. The error says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:14235:28
    at updateView (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:37839:30)
    at eventHook (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:37786:17)
    at Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:19725:28)
    at $state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:31686:22)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:18429:81)
    at http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:18515:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:19441:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:19267:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:11000/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js:19547:24)
```

I am using 1.0.0 beta 3 of the Ionic Framework. My app.js file looks like this:

```
"use strict";

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('intro', { url: '/', templateUrl: 'app/account/welcome.html', controller: 'WelcomeController' })
    .state('login', { url: '/account/login', templateUrl: 'app/account/login.html', controller: 'LoginController '})
  ;

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});

function WelcomeController($scope) {
}

function LoginController($scope) {
}
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>MyApp</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.min.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" animation="nav-title-slide-ios7">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <h1 class="title">MyApp</h1>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.html looks like this:

```
<ion-view>
  <br /><br />
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <a class="button" href="/#/account/login">Login</a>
</ion-view>
```

login.html looks like this:

```
<ion-view>
  <br /><br />
  <h1>Login</h1>
</ion-view>
```

The view transitions just fine. However, the error I showed above concerns me. I'm afraid its going to bite me in the ass later. Does anyone know what would be causing this? Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: dropping your code in codepen might be helpful

Comment: The multi-file structure of this question makes it impossible (I believe) to create a codepen.

Comment: Not really, check my jsfiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/ef36wee7/1/ and feel free to modify it to your perusal...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your using the bundle ionic.js file, you don't need to include ui-router, it already is included. You also don't need to include ng-router too.

[Heres the codepen](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/CAxFG)

Comment: If this question has been helpful, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach won't work for me. Your approach has all of the code as templates inside of a single .html file. My approach has multiple .html files.

Comment: If thats the case, then append the template url in your states provider with the folder name they are located in. I updated the codepen with a comment about that. Also, do not include the script tag to the external html files.

Answer (score 3):

ngRoute refers to the normal default router angular uses.

While you put that as your dependency, you cannot use the UI-router method, i.e stateProviders and the states.

In your case you have to remove ngRoute from your dependencies, or [ ]

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngRoute']);` to

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);`

and then troubleshoot further since its a null value, something else is broken.